# Eclipse Deployment Assembly different source and deploy path

Tags: java, deployment, path

In my eclipse properties I see at Deployment Assembly that some `Source` paths are linked to `Deploy` paths.

Which means in detail when i export my project into a `war` file and deploy it on a web/application server I get some `FileNotFound` Exceptions because of this behaviour.

I have two questions.

- Why is it necessary or what is the reason to change or redirect paths?
- What is best practice to get the correct path in both environments, IDE in my case eclipse and when the application is deployed?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue with classpath.

Example

```
classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
```